# How to make url for a document in document library publicly accessible?

Tags: sharepoint

I have Sharepoint 2010 hosted with windows authentication . I have created a document library inside a new site and uploaded few files.

Now,I'm trying to utilize the info of these files in some application using Rest Webservice exposed by sharepoint.
*http://{server_name}/{site}/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/{Document_Library_name}*

In the response I get xml containing details of files uploaded in document library. One of the tag in response of xml (inside src attribute of  tag) contains detail of url of file uploaded,

Now when I try to use this url for document display/download in my application/browser, it pops up with the window authentication which I have for Sharepoint site . After I provide correct user/password the document gets downloaded.

Is it somehow possible to make this document url public(I don't want window authentication pop up) ? At the same time I don't want to disable the Windows authentication for Sharepoint site .

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

By public do you mean accessible within your LAN or accessible from the internet given the sharepoint site is bound to an internet facing interface? I would imagine on the LAN it would be best to simply use the guest account for users who you wanted to give 'public' access to.

Bear in mind the only reason you're prompted for login details is probably because you're not using Internet Explorer.

Comment: By public means accessible from the internet without popup.I have equivalent Domain name ab2.xyz.com for sharepoint.After providing the user/pass to popup I'm able to download the file .I don't want pop up .

Comment: Check your settings in the Central Admin/Application Administration/Web Application, select the Web Application and then Anonymous Policy and see if its set or not.